# command line * linux

Tags: c, linux, shell, command-line

i'm trying to write code in C,which implements a simple calculator.

the input should come from the command line, so for example i if i run

```
./calculator 5 * 2
```

the result should be 10

the problem is that when i write * it shows all the files in the current directory and the program doesnt behave well.

there is anyway to overcome this problem?

i tried to find here or in other sites solutions,without success.

i need that * will Be interpreted as a char and not as a linux command.

thanks.

Comment: try `./calculator 5 "*" 2`

Comment: There was another question about this problem earlier today (US/Pacific time).  It's a standard issue.

Answer (score 4):

In linux shell, the `*` has special meaning. It is meant for globbing unless it is quoted like below

```
./calculator 5 '*' 2
```

You may also escape the asterisk to strip the special meaning from it

```
./calculator 5 \* 2
```

Comment: Hmm.. that was it.